# how to perform several returns in the reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a search string and filters. When this mechanism is activated, the entered data should be returned and then the logic should be executed, but I do not know how to perform 2 of these actions in one case.

```
    const objReducer = (state = objData, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
        case "ChangeObjects":
                    switch (action.name) {
                        case "find":
                            return {...state,FindStrokeText:action.text}
                            let copyState={...state,CurrentObjects: state.Objects.filter(f=>f.street.toLowerCase().includes(action.text.toLowerCase())).filter(f=>f.type.toLowerCase().includes(action.types)).filter(f=>Number(f.rooms)===Number(action.rooms))}
                            return copyState
                        case "choose":
                            return {...state,typeObj:action.text}
                            let copyState={...state,CurrentObjects: state.Objects.filter(f=>f.street.toLowerCase().includes(action.text.toLowerCase())).filter(f=>f.type.toLowerCase().includes(action.types)).filter(f=>Number(f.rooms)===Number(action.rooms))}
                            return copyState
                        case "NumberAp":
                            return {...state,numAp:action.text}
                            let copyState={...state,CurrentObjects: state.Objects.filter(f=>f.street.toLowerCase().includes(action.text.toLowerCase())).filter(f=>f.type.toLowerCase().includes(action.types)).filter(f=>Number(f.rooms)===Number(action.rooms))}
                            return copyState
                        default:
                            return state
                    }
            }
    }
export const ChangeObjects=(text,name)=>({
    type:"ChangeObjects",
    text,
    name
})
```

Comment: you can trigger multiple actions but not multiple returns. You trigger, `find` after that, in the same place that you trigger the action, you do your logic and after that trigger another action for the second return.